# How to use pyqtdeploy to freeze pyqt app?

Tags: pyqt5, pyqtdeploy

I have a project like this in below
[image]

And I want to freeze it to windows,android,ios app by `pyqtdeploy`.
There is few articles talk about how to freeze it,and official articles is very obscure for me, Can someone know how to use it to freeze app ?

[image]